# wcf AspNetCompatibilityRequirements

Tags: wcf

hi how to and where to use `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]` in vb(wcf). Im writing it in my .svc file 
but im not able to do.

giving me error

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out 
AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)> _